# I want to extract strings from a line

Tags: java, arrays, string

Below contents are available in a text file. I want to extract data (Name, age, Working experience, position). How can I do? I tried to extract using java stringtokenizer and split function. But cannot extract data.

```
Name                                     Age                   Working Experience          Position                     
John                                     23                    10                          Team Leader                          
Christian Elverdam                       27                    7                           Director                    
Niels Bye Nielsen                        59                    16                          Composer
Rajkumar Hirani                          40                    23                          Director               
Vidhu Vinod Chopra                      58                    21                          Screenplay
```

Expected ouput:

```
John              |23|10|Team Leader|
Christian Elverdam|27|7 |Director   |
Niels Bye Nielsen |59|16|Composer   |
Rajkumar Hirani   |40|23|Director   |
Vidhu Vinod Chopra|58|21|Screenplay |
```

Comment: Cam you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although **its use is discouraged in new code**. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

You can use [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) if you split on 2 or more spaces: `split(" {2,}")`

*Demo*

```
String input = "Name                                     Age                   Working Experience          Position                     \n" +
               "John                                     23                    10                          Team Leader                          \n" +
               "Christian Elverdam                       27                    7                           Director                    \n" +
               "Niels Bye Nielsen                        59                    16                          Composer\n" +
               "Rajkumar Hirani                          40                    23                          Director               \n" +
               "Vidhu Vinod Chopra                      58                    21                          Screenplay\n";

List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input))) {
    in.readLine(); // skip header line
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        rows.add(line.split(" {2,}"));
    }
}
for (String[] row : rows)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

*Output*

```
[John, 23, 10, Team Leader]
[Christian Elverdam, 27, 7, Director]
[Niels Bye Nielsen, 59, 16, Composer]
[Rajkumar Hirani, 40, 23, Director]
[Vidhu Vinod Chopra, 58, 21, Screenplay]
```